# How to display phone screen onto my rasberry pi 4

Tags: pi-4, raspbian-buster

Is there any way that I can use a usb cable or bluetooth to dispay my phone screen onto my rasberry pi, and therefor onto my tv?  i'm trying to use steamlink on my phone to play games from my computer at home, but the app on my pi requires a pin input on my actual computer, which I can't do becaue I don't have access to my computer.

Using an rpi4 with rasbian

Comment: Welcome! You are trying to stream Steamlink to your phone and then stream your phone to a RPi? Using Steamlink on the RPi only asks for the pin the first time, after that it should just connect.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to do, I had set up the pi with steam link and had it working a few weeks ago, then when I tried to boot up steam link again it asked for the pin, even though I had already put it in